# I can access an array, but not the elements within the array, when the elements were pushed through $.getJSON callback

Tags: arrays, undefined, getjson, element

I am trying to access the elements in an array that I created by looping through several $.getJSON callbacks with jQuery. If I console.log the array after the loop, I can see all the pushed elements within the array by expanding the array in my console. However, if I console.log any of the elements within the array, it returns "undefined" in the console. How can I gain access to the array AND its elements outside the callback?
Codepen: https://codepen.io/timfalk/pen/bLNmdV

```
    var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

var user = "";
var channels = [];

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    user = users[i];
    $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/" + user, function(channel) { 
      channels.push(channel);
    });
  }

console.log(channels); //returns fine with elements nested inside
console.log(channels[0]); //returns as undefined
```